# Always on without ambient mode? OR do not dim when enter ambient?

Tags: android, wear-os

For experiment/user study purpose, I need to keep my screen on for few minutes.
I have follow the guide from http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html and it works partially for my purpose.
The code allows my screen always on BUT it will enter ambient mode after few seconds. I DO NOT want ambient mode.

My trick is I commented out onEnterAmbient(), onUpdateAmbient() and onExitAmbient().
So that my screen drawing is still the same color (not changing to black & white).
HOWEVER the screen is DIMMED darker when entering ambient mode.
I don't want the DIMMED effect, I need to keep my screen as bright as possible for the duration of my user study.

Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

in your activity's `onCreate()` or use

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

in your activity's layout. See this [training](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) material for details.

Comment: ok it works. Actually I realized that before they release the ambient mode thing, I was using android:keepScreenOn="true" and it works well. But after I upgrade to use the new ambient mode feature, I suffer from the dimming problem. Anyway thanks for saving my day!