# How do I keep the screen from going off in Android Wear after a gesture has been detected?

Tags: android, wear-os

In my Android Wear app, if I don't touch the screen for a few seconds it enters ambient mode and the app exits. However, if I touch the screen it keeps it awake for a while longer and the app stays open. Is it possible to recreate this behaviour of keeping the app awake/open for a while after a shaking gesture instead of a screen press? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34971603/2765813

Comment: I still want the screen to dim after a certain period of time. I just want a gesture to work the same way as when you press the screen, in that it resets the timer which dims the screen.

Comment: That is when you clear the flag so system can dim your screen: getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); read the link that I had posted in the other solution