# How to keep an android wearable app always on AND constantly visible (preventing ambient mode)?

Tags: wear-os

I have an android wearable app developed as an Activity for targetSdkVersion22 and minSdkVerison20.  I am trying to update the app to targetSdkVersion27 and minSdkVersion23 as a Wearable Activity.  The app has to be "Always-on" and constantly visible and not go into ambient mode.  I have tried to follow the guidance at Android Wear Always-on Application [1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/always-on/index.html) and Keeping Your App Visible on Wear | Android Developers [2](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html), but they don't seem to address keeping the Wearable Activity from going into ambient-mode. I successfully can get control in the method:`

```
public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) 
{
...
```

and method:

```
public void onUpdateAmbient()
{
...
```

and method:

```
 public void onExitAmbient() 
 {
 ...
```

My question is how do I prevent the Wearable Activity from entering ambient mode in the first place?

Comment: A similar question 34971530 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971530/always-on-without-ambient-mode-or-do-not-dim-when-enter-ambient?s=7%7C106.0175) with answer worked. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Always on without ambient mode? OR do not dim when enter ambient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971530/always-on-without-ambient-mode-or-do-not-dim-when-enter-ambient)